# HQL query in grails for LIKE

Tags: sql, grails, hql

I want to know if HQL can handle a query such as the following

"find the values LIKE "abc" or "def" or ... in either column1 or column2 or Table1"

So I have multiple parameters, and I want to search two columns wildcard for any of the parameter values.

I am doing grails, and if preferable would like to use the executeQuery function, but not sure how to write this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply any of the [HQL Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) to your query.  For example:

```
from Table1 where column1 like :param1 or column2 like :param2
```

You have to apply the `%` operator in the parameters themselves however.

---

You can also perform your query using the GORM [criteria builder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.2%20Criteria) with Hibernate [criterion restrictions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html):

```
Table1.withCriteria {
    like('column1', param1)
    or {
        like('column2', param2)
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a criteria query instead:

```
def criteria = Table1.createCriteria()

def results = criteria.listDistinct {
    or {
        or {
            like('column1', "%abc%")
            like('column1', "%def%")
        }

        or {
            like('column2', "%abc%")
            like('column2', "%def%")
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to exclude duplicates replace `listDistinct` with `list`. I haven't tested the above, so it's probably riddled with errors, but hopefully will prove to be of some help.